# Plotting of complex exponential function using Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am using matlab to plot complex exponential function.But i am not getting the required waveform as output.
My Signal is exp ( j2πmf ) where m takes various positive values.

My code is shown below.

```
    close all;
    clc;
    f= -0.5:0.5;
    Rez = cos(2*pi*1*f);
    Imz = sin(2*pi*1*f)*j;
    z = Rez + Imz;
    z_n = exp(z);
    plot(f,z_n);
    xlabel('Frequency ->');
    ylabel('Amplitude->');
    grid on
    axis tight
```

My Output Signal [image: Output]

But I want the signal shown below as my output

[image: Required Output]

Comment: Try f = -0.5:0.01:0.5 to increase the samples along the frequency axis (using a smaller plotting interval).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you try to make a plot of complex numbers z_n.
This does not make any sense.
You can plot the real part (real(z_n), the imaginary part (imag(z_n) or the absolute values (abs(z_n).

However, your exceptions in the second diagram are wrong too.
Your function  exp(j2πmf) is a rotating vector with absolute amplitude 1.

This results in:

1. real(exp(j2πmf) = cos(2πmf)
2. imag (exp(j2πmf) = sin(2πmf); By the way, imag does not include j, it is the value which has j as a factor.
3. abs(exp(j2πmf) = 1